# Print several lines after nth occurence in bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, perl

I'm looking for a way to search for the nth occurrence of a pattern and print k lines after the pattern. I guess `awk` would work better than `grep` in this case but I cannot figure out the way to do it properly ...

Say I have the following text file:

```
Draft  
blablablabla  
tralalalalala  
Draft  
blablablabla  
tralalalalala  
Draft  
important line 1  
important line 2  
Draft   
blablablabla   
tralalalalala
```

In this case `n=3` and `k=2`, I want to print the 2 lines following the 3th occurrence of the pattern "Draft". In my specific case, n and k may vary.

Is it a simple way to do this ?

Comment: I wrote a python script I call grepl.  I run it like this: `grepl --lines=10 foo bar` - it works just like your perl answer but I can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` and `tail` to achieve this:

```
$ n=3
$ k=2
$ grep -m "$n" -A "$k" 'Draft' input.txt | tail -n "$k"
important line 1  
important line 2  
$
```

The `-m "$n"` option to grep specifies to stop after the `n`th match, and `-A "$k"` tells grep to output `k` lines from after each match.  We then pipe this to `tail -b "$k"` to output only those `k` lines.

Answer (score 7):

Perl to the rescue:

```
 perl -sne '$c++ if /Draft/;
            if ($c == $n) { print scalar <> for 1 .. $k; }
           ' -- -n=3 -k=2 < input
```

- `-s` parses the switches `-n=3` and creates the variables.
- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `<>` the diamond operator reads from the input.
- [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) is needed to read only one line from the input, otherwise [print](http://p3rl.org/print) would force list context on the diamond operator and print all the remaining lines.

Answer (score 5):

awk: print the lines between the 3rd and 4th "Draft" lines.

```
awk -v n=3 '/Draft/ { p = (++num == n) ; next }; p' file
```

There's an optimization to be made: exit when the 4th Draft is seen.

Answer (score 1):

Via `awk`

```
awk -v "k=2" -v "n=3" \
    '/^Draft/ {i++} 
    i==n-1 && x==0 {x++;next} 
    x>=1 && x<=k {print;x++} 
    x>k {exit}' foo
```

- `/^Draft/ {i++}` increment `i` to count `Draft`
- `i==n-1 && x==0 {x++; next}` skip the line with the `n`nd occurrence of `Draft` and set `x` to print the first line after the the `n`nd `Draft`
- `x>=1 && x<=k {print;x++}` print the next `k` lines
- `x>k {exit}` and exit

Comment: you don't need the line continuations inside a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -ne'/^\(.*\n\)*Draft *$/G'  \
     -e's/\n/&/3;t$' -e'N;D;:$'  \
     -e's///g;//!n;N;G;s/\n//2'  \
     -etq -e/.$/b$ -e:q -e'p;q' <in >out
```

---

```
important line 1
important line 2
```